# Why I can not Update File Permission to owner? (Google.Apis.Drive.v3)

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I upload the file with service acconut, then I want transfer the owner permission to my own account, But it always throw an exception which is "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."

I read offcial document say the field "role" is writable.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/update

Where do I need to Correction?

My api version is Google Apis Drive v3

Here is sample code I copied at google developers

```
 try
        {
            // First retrieve the permission from the API.
            Permission permission = service.Permissions.Get(fileId, permissionId).Execute();
            permission.Role = newRole;
            return service.Permissions.Update(permission, fileId, permissionId).Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }

        return null;
```

After Execute(), I got this error message.

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable. [403] Errors [Message[The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.] Location[ - ] Reason[fieldNotWritable] Domain[global]]

---

(Update)

I changed my code with

```
public Permission ModifyPermission(DriveService service, string fileId, string permissionId, string newRole)
    {
        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newRole)) return null;

            var permission = new Permission
            {
                Role = newRole
            };

            var request = service.Permissions.Update(permission, fileId, permissionId);

            if(newRole == "owner") request.TransferOwnership = true;

            return request.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Then it throw another exception.

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file. [403]
>   Errors [
>       Message[The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientFilePermissions] Domain[global]
>   ]

The File was upload by service account credential in JSON. And I update permission is as same credential as upload. 
What am I missing?

Comment: insert new permissions dont update it.

Answer (score 0):

The permission object that you are providing, has more properties filled than accepted by the drive api.

For example, the properties *Kind* and *Type* are filled when a permission is retrieved by using the get method.

Only the following properties of a permission are allowed when using the update method: *expirationTime*, *role*.

See: [Permissions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update), section **Request body**.

You could try this:

```
try
{
    var permission = new Permission
    {
        Role = newRole
    };
    return service.Permissions.Update(permission, fileId, permissionId).Execute();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
}

return null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your suggest. It works, but the exception is instead of "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file".
I called api by service account JSON credential, it should have permission to modify.

Comment: Does the user have write access to the file? See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid) for some additional error information which may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, The File have 2 permissions. One is service account, another one is the User which permission field role is "writer".